# Populate JQuery DataTable with my json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm suggested to use JQuery data table. Now I need to populate grid with bunch of json objects sent from my controller. How can I send this data on the grid from js

```
$.ajax({
            ...
            url: '/Home/ReturnJsonData',
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                    // this is where I should sent item object to my grid
                });
            },

            error: function () { alert("error"); }
        });
```

**Update**
I've found these [link](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html), but I dont know how to implement it.

Comment: So why don't you parse the result, and create a table element then push the result's elements as rows, finally activate jQuery DataTable ?

Comment: @IssaQandil can you show me on concrete example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JQuery DataTable sAjaxSource property to specify ajaxsource in your case it would be /HomeReturnJsonData

An example follow

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "Home/ReturnJsonData",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "ID",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                            return '<a href=\"Details/' + 
                            oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                        }
                    },
                    { "sName": "COMPANY_NAME" },
                    { "sName": "ADDRESS" },
                    { "sName": "TOWN" }
                ]
 });
});
```

Comment: these is fine when I need on page init to display data, but in my case I need to send data on js success: function (result) { } block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Jquery Grid Plugin** in that case.

Read this article to use MVC Data Grid: using jqGrid and JSON

http://blog.davidrenz.com/?p=663

**Update:**

In that case if you only want to use J-query Datatable go to this link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm interested in data table implementation.

Comment: jqGrid has to be even more brain-dead than DataTables (which is awkward, but *at least it supports a function to fetch the data from a different async* which is such a trivial concept that would actually make the grid much simpler) when dealing with remote data.

Answer (score 0):

I put this in a function because that was the easiest way to do it for me, feel free to copy the function and use it. All your going to need to change is the url and the column names and number there of. To call it just copy the html with the paths done so that they match whatever yours are.

```
function SetUpGrid(tableID, pagerID, data) {
    $("#" + tableID).jqGrid({
        url: '/pagename/stuff?data=' + data,
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['col name1', 'col name2', ... 'col nameN'],
        colModel: [
      { name: 'colName1', index: 'colName1', align: "center", sortable: true, editable: false, resizable: false },
      { name: 'colName2', index: 'colName2', align: "center", sortable: true, editable: false, resizable: false },
      ...
      { name: 'colNameN', index: 'colNameN', align: "center", sortable: true, editable: false, resizable: false }
    ],
    pager: '#' + pagerID,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    rowNum: 15,
    pgbuttons: true,
    pginput: false,
    pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}",
    recordtext: "Data {0} - {1} of {2}",
    emptyrecords: "No data to display",
    loadui: true,
    rowList: [15, 30, 60],
    scrollrows: true,
    hidegrid: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    beforeRequest: function () { // This just inserts a loading image, you don't need it but I was loading a lot of data and wanted the user to know something was happening.
        $("#" + tableID).empty().append('<tr><td><img src="/Content/imgs/loading.gif" /></td></tr>');
    },
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        /*
        Called when the json load is done, this is a way to insert the data the way I want to.
        Feel free to use whatever you want like links or <p>s or <div>s or whatever.
        */
        if (data.length > 1) {
            for (var key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    $("#" + tableID).empty().append("<tr><td>" + data[key].colName1 + "</td><td>" + data[key].colName12+ "</td> ... <td>" + data[key].colNameN + "</td></tr>");
                }
            }
        } else {
            $("#" + tableID).empty().append("<tr><td>" + this.colName1 + "</td><td>" + this.colName2 + "</td> ... <td>" + this.colNameN + "</td></tr>");
        }
    },
    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Called when an error occurs, handle as you wish, if you even do.
        alert(xhr);
        alert(status);
        alert(error);
    }
});
$("#" + tableID).jqGrid("navGrid", "#" + pagerID, { add: false, edit: false, refresh: false, del: false, search: false }).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);
}

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ADTFunding.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        SetUpFundingGrid('dataTable', 'pager', '9895998');
    });
</script>
<table id="dataTable"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `fnAddData` property to push json to table. Check this article https://jqueryajaxphp.com/jquery-datatable-using-json/

Comment: The link is dead :(