# Ajax POST request and display in DataTable jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am receiving JavaScript object from the url I am calling, but DataTable needs a JSON array. How do I edit the code so that I can generate the table body?

```
$('#users-table').DataTable ({
    "serverSide" : true,
    "ajax" : {
        method : 'POST',
        url : "office/findUser"
    },
    'columns' : [
        {data : "id"},
        {data : "firstName"},
        {data : "lastName"},
        {data : "role"},
        {data : "zone"},
        {data : "contact"},
    ],
    'select' : 'single'
});
```

The 'data' I am receiving is an array of objects. How do I make this happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate JQuery DataTable with my json data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384053/populate-jquery-datatable-with-my-json-data)

Comment: Please post a sample of your JSON response.